# Django app under mod_wsgi - how to not consume url

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi

I have a Django app that I am porting from mod_python to mod_wsgi.

Under mod_python, I was able to map http://example.com/A and http://example.com/B to the same Django app. However, http://example.com/C (or anything not specified) would not invoke python, wsgi, or Django at all.

In addition, Django was still able to "see" the "/A" and "/B" at the start of the path.

In contrast, when I configure with mod_wsgi, I can get my Django app running with a simple WSGIScriptAlias directive:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/wsgi.py
```

but this method lets my Django app handle "/C" (and any invalid path), which I do not want.

So I tried this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /A /path/to/my/wsgi.py
WSGIScriptAlias /B /path/to/my/wsgi.py
```

This method invokes my Django app, but the Django app doesn't "see" the "/A" nor "/B" part of the url.

Finally, placing the `WSGIScriptAlias` inside a `<Location>` gives the error:

```
WSGIScriptAlias not allowed here
```

How can I configure mod_wsgi so that the first part of the path is passed to Django, and Apache will only pass a few paths to Django, and all such paths get passed to the same Django app?

Here is my old mod_python config, which worked:

```
<Location "/A/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE path.to.my.django.settings
</Location>

<Location "/B/">
    SetHandler python-program
    PythonHandler django.core.handlers.modpython
    SetEnv DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE path.to.my.django.settings
</Location>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /A /path/to/my/wsgi.py/A
WSGIScriptAlias /B /path/to/my/wsgi.py/B
```

Comment: Perfect! Where can I find documentation about this feature? I don't see it at https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIScriptAlias .. Is it just part of the WSGI standard?

Comment: That it works this way is because of how Apache handles mapping the likes of Alias/ScriptAlias directives, and so WSGIScriptAlias directive since it relies on the same mechanisms in Apache. It has absolutely nothing to do with the WSGI specification, which says nothing about specific servers. Apache documentation in http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html says a bit about adding back parts of matched URL to file system target, but how that affects SCRIPT_NAME in CGI/WSGI isn't explained anywhere that I know of.

Comment: BTW, the examples in Apache documentation use Match variants of directives, patterns and variable substation. Since this was a fixed mapping I dispensed with that. Technically though you could have combined the two above into one WSGIScriptAliasMatch directive with an appropriate pattern and variable substitution on filesystem target.